# How to parse an specific element stored in a json array by a non-fixed path?

Tags: postgresql

A table stored JSON arrays in PostgreSQL database. I can't parse the specific key-value, because they are in non-fixed order.
For example,

```
[
      {
        "name": "Wu"
      },
      {
        "age": 20,
      },
      {
        "Sex": "Male"
      }
]
```

and next row stored like:

```
[
      {
        "Sex": "Female"
      },
      {
        "age": 10
      },
      {
        "name": "Chen",
      }
]
```

I read PostgreSQL's document, it seems those functions always need a fixed path to parse.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: your example has a spurious comma in the JSON I'm assuming that's a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnest the array and use aggregate functions to re-flatten it.

```
create temp table t(id int,j json) ; 
insert into t values(42,'[{"name": "Wu"},{"age": 20},{"Sex": "Male"}]'),(86,'[{"Sex": "Female"},{"age": 10 },{"name": "Chen" }]');



select t.id, 
    max(e->>'age') as age,
    max(e->>'name') as name
FROM t, 
    LATERAL json_array_elements(t.j) AS e
GROUP BY t.id;



SELECT t.id, 
    max(e->>'age') as age,
    max(e->>'Sex') as sex
FROM t, 
    LATERAL json_array_elements(t.j) AS e
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING  max(e->>'name') = 'Chen';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It solved my problem successfully.
By the way, I found "json_to_recordset" function has similar effects.